# Repopulating hidden fields with CodeIgniter Form Validation class

Tags: forms, validation, codeigniter, repopulation

I am stuck how to repopulate a hidden field in a form after an unsuccessful form validation.

The repopulation uses set_value() function to print out the chosen value for other fields, but with the hidden field, there is already something printed in the value field.

Here is my view code:

```
<? echo validation_errors();?>
<? echo form_open('projects/start');?>
<input type="hidden" name="project_type_id" value="<? echo $this->uri->segment(3);?>" >
<input type="text" name="site" value="<?echo set_value('site');?>">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
<?echo form_close();?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the URI segment value in second parameter, after submit the form it will take the submitted value, It repopulate submitted value not URI segment value.

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('projects/start'); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="project_type_id" value="<?php echo set_value('project_type_id', $this->uri->segment(3)); ?>" />
<input type="text" name="site" value="<?php echo set_value('site'); ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Hope this helps you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess here that you want to fill it with the URI segment when it first loads, and that this is not available once the form submits.

Perhaps this would work

```
<input type="hidden" name="project_type_id" value="<? echo ($this->input->post())? set_value('project_type_id'): $this->uri->segment(3);?>" >
```

Depending on how you built your site it might also be possible to do

```
<? echo form_open('projects/start/' . $this->uri->segment(3));?>
```

To keep the URI